# split objects in a list separated by ',' in python

Tags: python

I have a list of elements. for each element I want to split into 3 numbers separated by ',' and print them.

My code is not doing what I want. :S

```
l = ['14,23,63\n','41,20,76\n','65,23,42\n']
for element in l:
    element.split(',')
    print element[0],element[1],element[2] #outcome should be e.g. 14,23,63
```

Comment: You forgot to store the split elements in a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str.split` returns a new list.

```
for element in l:
    parts = element.split(',')
    print parts
```

Also you probably want to trim as well (`element.strip().split(',')`).

Answer (score 3):

```
print [map(int, x.split(",")) for x in l]
```

prints

```
[[14, 23, 63], [41, 20, 76], [65, 23, 42]]
```

This not only splits the strings, it also converts the elements to integers, thereby implicitely stripping the newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
splitElements = element.split(',')
print splitElements[0],splitElements[1],splitElements[2]
```